# Parquet file in Spark SQL

Tags: apache-spark

I am trying to use Spark SQL using parquet file formats. When I try the basic example :

```
object parquet {

  case class Person(name: String, age: Int)

  def main(args: Array[String]) {

    val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("HdfsWordCount")
    val sc = new SparkContext(sparkConf)
    val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
    // createSchemaRDD is used to implicitly convert an RDD to a SchemaRDD.
    import sqlContext.createSchemaRDD

    val people = sc.textFile("C:/Users/pravesh.jain/Desktop/people/people.txt").map(_.split(",")).map(p => Person(p(0), p(1).trim.toInt))
    people.saveAsParquetFile("C:/Users/pravesh.jain/Desktop/people/people.parquet")

    val parquetFile = sqlContext.parquetFile("C:/Users/pravesh.jain/Desktop/people/people.parquet")
  }
}
```

I get a null pointer exception :

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
>   at org.apache.spark.parquet$.main(parquet.scala:16)

which is the line saveAsParquetFile. What's the issue here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error occurs when I was using Spark in eclipse in Windows. I tried the same on spark-shell and it works fine. I guess spark might not be 100% compatible with windows.

Answer (score 1):

Spark is compatible with Windows. You can run your program in a spark-shell session in Windows or you can run it using spark-submit with necessary argument such as "-master" (again, in Windows or other OS).
You cannot just run your Spark program as an ordinary Java program in Eclispe without properly setting up the Spark environment and so on. You problem has nothing to do with Windows.